# Worklight Adapter singleStepAuth security test

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

I have multiple adapters that are public and require authentication. 
Some of my adapters use a common adapter procedure that should not be visible to the public, but only visible to my adapters. Is there a way to create, a sort of private procedure which will be accessed only by other adapters?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you put in an adapter is not public. No client can see this code. So you can put your method in one of the adapters and use it from other adapters. 
More information regarding this issue can be found here:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_11_Advanced_adapter_usage_and_mashup.pdf

Comment: Ok I am not sure if mashup will exactly solve the problem. Because from the link which you provided, what if I want to make 'getYahooWeather' accessible only to 'SQLAdapter'? Further there is also a requirement to make 'getYahooWeather' accessible only to 'SQLAdapter' before authentication and accessible to client(everyone) after authentication. Please let me know.

Comment: The terms private and public is not relevant to adapters. adapters are kind of web-service that you can connect to. You can protect your adapter by using a security-test. if you want some procedure to be protected but can be called freely from another adapter you can protect it by a security test that uses some User Name / Password protection and use this credentials when you call it from the other adapter procedure. There is no way AFAIK to grant access from SQL Adapter only.